# Footer hides content of the div above it

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Here is the link to codesandbox where I am trying to add a footer but the content above it gets hidden. How can I fix this? What is the mistake I am doing?

The footer component is commented in the app.js file. Scroll to the bottom and see the content and if you uncomment the footer, it will hide the content.

https://codesandbox.io/s/rk4kl

Comment: your footer has `position: absolute` remove it and it will work.

Comment: That or change the value to `relative` so that you can still make use of the positioning (i.e. `bottom: 0;`)

Comment: @PriyankKachhela removing position absolute doesn't help.  If I have less content, then the footer will not be at the bottom of the page. Removing it doesn't help. Make sure you try the solution once before commenting.

Comment: @YongPin I didn't get you :|

Comment: Instead of using `position: absolute;` you can use `position: relative;`. It's so you can still use the `bottom: 0;` property.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is using the *position* property in the wrong place.
the *position* property is good especially when you're considering boxes.

in your ***styles.css***

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
```

change it into

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.footer {
  min-height: 2vh;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 90vh;
}
```

**Explanation:**
The main idea is that for keeping the footer always have to split the viewport into separate ratios. So that they can always stay with that ratio irrespective of the content.
here the div with className *App* have a min-height of 100vh, which means when we split the viewport into 100 pieces div with App occupies a minimum of 100 slices. Now inside App, we have the flex and footer. We give flex a minimum of 90 pieces and a footer of a minimum of 2. so the footer will always keep in the bottom now.

here is the updated [result](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-burnell-xq43e)

Comment: This is a good solution. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Just change `position: absolute;` to `position: relative;`

```
 .footer {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  
}
```

Comment: `position: block` is not a valid CSS statement, you mean to just remove `position: absolute`.

Comment: Sorry my mistake

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for some "Sticky Footer" Solutions, if your Content is not long enough, the footer should be at the end of the page.
You could give a margin-top - footer height.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
 background-color: blue;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.content-inside {
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.footer {
background-color: yellow;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-inside">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">Here comes the Footer</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use from position `static` instead `absolute` for  **.footer**.

When you use `position: absolute` for an element, it may be placed over other elements. because:

**Absolute positioned elements are removed from the normal flow and can overlap elements.**

From: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just remove position "absolute" or add position "relative" to it.

```
 .footer {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;  
}
```